# How do I determine the require order for my gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, require

I'm [working on a gem](https://github.com/mockdeep/mutant-rails) that for now just requires a handful of other gems. The problem I'm running into is that the `mutant` gem needs to be required after the other two, but when I add my gem to a Gemfile in a Rails project, `mutant` loads before the other two. How can I make it so that when my gem is required, that the other two gems are loaded first?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, they are loaded in the order they are listed withing your gemfile. Add mutant after the gems you want loaded first.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I want to require them in the right order within my gem. So if somebody adds my gem to their gemfile, it automatically includes the other 3 gems in the correct order.